# EVA + Corresponding Node References + Views + Sort by Order of Appearance on Page Node

Tags: nodes, entities, views

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions with this problem. I will try to be as clear as possible. Basically, what I want to do is customize my Page node "County" to show a table of "Organization" nodes (along with their contact information) referenced in the county node.

So what I have done is to use the EVA + Corresponding Node References modules to create a table view on my county page. The problem is that I cannot figure out how to configure Views so it will list the organizations in the same order that I referenced them in the county node --  See screenshot http://www.diigo.com/item/image/16wo5/0jmw. As you can see from my screenshot I have ordered them first "Org 3" and then "Org 1", but in the views table they are ordered first "Org 1" and then "Org 3".

From reading other posts I suspect that I need to add a relationship in my view but I feel like I have tried almost everything and I still can't get it to sort correctly. Here's a screenshot of my Views admin page -- http://www.diigo.com/item/image/16wo5/x7hr

Thanks again for any help.

-Scott

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I figured this out after some ideas I got while researching kalabro's answer. Basically I needed a better understanding of the logic of how EVA works with node references and related objects in views. So here's what I did --

First I changed the contextual filter in my view to "Content: Nid" with a default value of "Content ID from URL". Next I added a relationship to the field "Related Org" (which is the node reference field in my County content type) and did not check "require this relationship. Then I filtered my results to only include County content types and added the "Related Org" relationship to the title and body of my included fields -- except for the first title field (the related county itself) which I used to group the related organization by. Finally, I removed all sort criteria from the table settings and from the sort section.

Here's a screen shot of my views set-up: http://www.diigo.com/item/image/16wo5/7chr

Here's a screen shot of my county view: http://www.diigo.com/item/image/16wo5/r1dx

After thinking about this problem some more I'm not sure that I actually needed to create the corresponding node reference in order to accomplish this. I haven't tested it yet. Also, there may still be some tweaks to this set-up that don't show up because of my limited testing. Still, I feel like I'm on the right path now with a better understanding of how EVA, node references, contexts and relationships work together in views. And I am definitely left with a greater appreciation of the power of Drupal 7.

If anyone wants more details about my set-up please let me know.

Thanks to kalabro for helping me to get started thinking in a different direction.

-Scott

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use 2 references at the same time. If you prefer your «Related Org» field, you don't need EVA at all. Just customize display settings for your «Related Org» field.
[image]

Help link: http://drupaleasy.com/blogs/ryanprice/2009/08/theming-nodereference-or-reusing-complex-data-drupal